# Next.js - generate persistent layout with getStaticProps at build time

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel

I am using this pattern for building persistent layouts in Next.js: [Persistent Layout Patterns in Next.js](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/)

It works fine when your layout doesn't rely on external data.

What to do if you want to build a documentation like page - and in your layout there is a sidebar with sections like `Getting Started`, `Examples`, `FAQ`, `About`? Ideally I would like to store those sections in a markdown file and generate the layout at the build time.

```
// markdown file
---
section_1: "Getting Started"
section_2: "Examples"
section_3: "FAQ"
section_4: "About"
---
```

How to achieve such functionality with Next.JS and `getStaticProps`?

Answer (score 2):

`getStaticProps` can be used only in a page, so it's not an option to generate layout component.

You can extend the build process by writing a custom Node.js script that will read the markdown and create a `.json` file with the sidebar sections.

The created `.json` file can be imported in the `Layout` component on a client-side.

You would need to extend npm script `build` in the `package.json`, so `next build` and your script would run with one command.